# Открытие блоков независимо друг от друга

Tags: html, jquery, css

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/VzQNgM
При разрешении менее 500 px 2 кнопки "contacts" и "menu". если кликнуть на "menu" а затем на "contacs" содержимое двух кнопок отображается вместе. Нужно чтобы было независимо: клик на menu-отображение содержимого, клик на contacts-содержимое menu сворачивается и появляется содержимое contacts. И с contacts в точности наоборот. 
Мучаюсь с этим вопросом, как лучше?? ссылку на codepen привел

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle(500);
  });//end slide toggle
  
  $(window).resize(function() {  
  if (  $(window).width() > 500 ) {   
   $('.menu').removeAttr('style');
   }
 });//end resize
});//end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы при клике на "menu" содержимое "contacts" сворачивалось нужно проверить виден ли '.contacts' или нет если виден то  свернуть. И наоборот.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    if ($('.contacts').is(':visible')) { //Проверка на видемость
        $('.contacts').toggle(500);
    }
    $('.menu').toggle(500);
  });//end slide toggle

  $(window).resize(function() {     
        if (  $(window).width() > 500 ) {           
            $('.menu').removeAttr('style');
        }
    });//end resize
});//end ready


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger2').click(function() {
    // debugger;
    if ($('.menu').is(':visible')) {//Проверка на видемость
        $('.menu').toggle(500);
    }
    $('.contacts').toggle(500);
  });//end slide toggle

  $(window).resize(function() {     
        if (  $(window).width() > 500 ) {           
            $('.contacts').removeAttr('style');
         }
    });//end resize
});//end ready
```